# Access 2013 - Query not returning correct Number of Results

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

I am trying to get the query below to return the TWO lowest `PlayedTo` results for each `PlayerID`.

```
select
    x1.PlayerID, x1.RoundID, x1.PlayedTo
from P_7to8Calcs as x1
where
    (
    select count(*)
    from P_7to8Calcs as x2
    where x2.PlayerID = x1.PlayerID
    and x2.PlayedTo <= x1.PlayedTo
    ) <3
order by PlayerID, PlayedTo, RoundID;
```

Unfortunately at the moment it doesn't return a result when there is a tie for one of the lowest scores. A copy of the dataset and code is here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4a9fc/13.

`PlayerID` 47 has only one result returned as there are two different `RoundID`'s that are tied for the second lowest `PlayedTo`. For what I am trying to calculate it doesn't matter which of these two it returns as I just need to know what the number is but for reporting I ideally need to know the one with the newest date.

One other slight problem with the query is the time it takes to run. It takes about 2 minutes in Access to run through the 83 records but it will need to run on about 1000 records when the database is fully up and running.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes That will be true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolve the tie by adding `DatePlayed` to your internal sorting (you wanted the one with the newest date anyway):

```
select
    x1.PlayerID, x1.RoundID
    , x1.PlayedTo
from P_7to8Calcs as x1
where
    (
    select count(*)
    from P_7to8Calcs as x2
    where x2.PlayerID = x1.PlayerID
    and (x2.PlayedTo < x1.PlayedTo
         or x2.PlayedTo = x1.PlayedTo
            and x2.DatePlayed >= x1.DatePlayed
         )
    ) <3
order by PlayerID, PlayedTo, RoundID;
```

For performance create an index supporting the join condition. Something like:

```
create index P_7to8Calcs__PlayerID_RoundID on P_7to8Calcs(PlayerId, PlayedTo);
```

Note: I used your SQLFiddle as I do not have Acess available here.

---

Edit: In case the index does not improve performance enough, you might want to try the following query using window functions (which avoids nested sub-query). It works in your SQLFiddle but I am not sure if this is supported by Access.

```
select x1.PlayerID, x1.RoundID, x1.PlayedTo
from (
  select PlayerID, RoundID, PlayedTo
  , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY PlayerId ORDER BY PlayedTo, DatePlayed DESC) AS Rank
  from P_7to8Calcs
  ) as x1
where x1.RANK < 3
order by PlayerID, PlayedTo, RoundID;
```

See [OVER clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) and [Ranking Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx) for documentation.

Comment: Where does the create index statement go in relation to the result of the query?

Comment: The index is part of the schema. It has to be created before running the query in order to have any effect. The index will not affect the result in any way, just the performance.

Comment: See as this is a query of a query in access I'm not sure how you go about adding the index. Besides the code you suggested works great and still has about the same run time so i will just have to see what happens when the database is fully up. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately the second option you put up returns a syntax error (missing operator) message in access.